# Control Status Registers in Java

Tags: java

I'm using Java to, essentially, write device drivers for I2C devices.  The processor is an Arm on a BeagleBoneBlack board, but I don't think that is particularly relevant to the question I have, especially because we might be moving off of the BBB platform in the not too distant future.

I am looking for a way to cleanly access hardware control/status registers from Java.  The bits and bitfields in CSRs are defined by the chip datasheets - neither I nor Java get to determine them.  The driver usually needs to do operations to control registers like set named bits, clear named bits, and modify multi-bit bitfields.  And from status registers determine if particular bits are set or cleared, or what the values are of bitfields.  And, occasionally, write the status register back to the control register to clear the interrupts (Write One To Clear). At first it seemed like Enums and Enumsets would work, but I haven't figured out how to make them work with pre-defined hardware registers.

What I am looking for is a class that allows me to define bits and bitfields in registers that might be byte, word, or longword (i.e., arbitrary) length, and then do sets and checks on those bits/bitfields.  In C I would just create a bunch of #defines with the appropriate bitmasks and then use some non-obvious code to do the necessary bit manipulations, but I was hoping for something more clear and concise in Java.

Does anyone have any suggestions or examples for this type of class in Java?

Comment: Well judging by the primitives you want, their all built in. `byte`, `String`, `long`, etc.

Comment: This may help for bitwise operations: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: Java certainly isn't any better at this than C. You'll probably have to deal with the usual bitwise operations, only with no macros (which is both a good and a bad thing).

Comment: @frayment - thank you, but I was hoping to find something a bit more OO and a bit less like the traditional C bitmasks and obscure bitwise manipulations.  Also, Java's lack of an unsigned byte and its habit of making bytes into ints (with sign extension) at almost every operation makes using the built-in primitives difficult.  What I am looking for, for example, is a way to designate that bit 4 in a particular register is known as chipCfg, and that I want to do tests on it to see if it is set or clear, or manipulations on it to set, clear, or toggle it.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov, yes, I have found all of the bit manipulations I know and "love" from C, but the constant sign extension when the bytes are 'promoted' to ints is a pain, and I had a relatively clean way to deal with all the macros in C.

In the last couple of days I have fleshed out the driver, but I am not happy with my implementation of the enumerations of the various bits in the control and status registers.  True, the bit locations are defined and known in only one place, but the amount of code effort required to maintain that abstraction is surprising large.

Comment: Yes, signed-only types is a two-edged sword. It eliminates the confusion about whether something is signed or not, but it also a pain when dealing with unsigned values. A common trick is to use `b & 0xFF` if you want to promote a byte into an "unsigned" int (and avoid using bytes and shorts at all whenever you can). And no, Java doesn't have anything OO-like for bit manipulations. It's just not that kind of language.

Comment: @JohnDeRoo `I want a way to designate that bit 4 in *n* register is known as *foo*` Take a look at HashMaps and HashSets!